# How to store multiple values for the same key in an NSDictionary, given an NSArray of JSON objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I know it's not possible to set multiple values for the same key, unless the values are stored in an array.

I have this NSArray called `friMainDicArray` of JSON objects:

```
{
        day = 0;
        "end_time" = "17:30";
        "english_event" = "Lion Dance";
        "english_performer" = "Legendary Group";
        "image_link" = "schedule_miss_vn";
        stage = 0;
        "start_time" = "17:00";
        "viet_event" = "<null>";
        "viet_performer" = "Nh?m Legendary";
    },
        {
        day = 0;
        "end_time" = "18:00";
        "english_event" = Singing;
        "english_performer" = "Ivan Cheong";
        "image_link" = "schedule_miss_vn";
        stage = 0;
        "start_time" = "17:30";
        "viet_event" = "Ca Nh?c";
        "viet_performer" = "Ivan Cheong";
    },
        {
        day = 0;
        "end_time" = "22:00";
        "english_event" = Singing;
        "english_performer" = "Between California and Summer";
        "image_link" = "";
        stage = 0;
        "start_time" = "21:00";
        "viet_event" = "Ca Nh?c";
        "viet_performer" = "";
    },
        {
        day = 0;
        "end_time" = "";
        "english_event" = "End of Day";
        "english_performer" = "";
        "image_link" = "";
        stage = 0;
        "start_time" = "22:00";
        "viet_event" = "";
        "viet_performer" = "";
    },
        {
        day = 0;
        "end_time" = "21:00";
        "english_event" = Music;
        "english_performer" = "DJ Happee From Channel 93.3";
        "image_link" = "";
        stage = 0;
        "start_time" = "20:00";
        "viet_event" = "";
        "viet_performer" = "";
    },
        {
        day = 0;
        "end_time" = "21:00";
        "english_event" = Music;
        "english_performer" = "Adam Cease";
        "image_link" = "";
        stage = 0;
        "start_time" = "20:00";
        "viet_event" = "";
        "viet_performer" = "";
    },
        {
        day = 0;
        "end_time" = "21:00";
        "english_event" = "Ao Dai Fashion Show";
        "english_performer" = "";
        "image_link" = "";
        stage = 0;
        "start_time" = "20:00";
        "viet_event" = "";
        "viet_performer" = "";
    }
}
```

I am storing each JSON object, given the `start_time` key value, but the problem is with the `20:00` key. I would like to store the `20:00` as the key, and the JSON object as the values. The problem is, the last 3 JSON objects contain the same `20:00` key, so I would like to store those 3 JSON objects as an NSArray, and set it for the `20:00` key.

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [friMainDicArray count]; i++)
{
    [friMainDic setValue:friMainDicArray[i] forKey:[friMainDicArray[i] valueForKey:@"start_time" ] ]
}
```

However, I don't know exactly the logic to check if the `start_time` key is the same, then add its value to the same key.

Can someone point me in the right way?

Comment: So what is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can loop the array and before setValueForKey, you check if the key already exists, if it is yes, and if value for that key is of type NSDictionary, you combine the current one with the existing one as an array, otherwise value for that key should be a NSArray, you then add the current item to that array.

```
for (NSDictionary *item in friMainDicArray)
{
    NSString *key = [item valueForKey:@"start_time"];
    if ([friMainDic objectForKey:key]) {
        id value = [friMainDic objectForKey:key];
        if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray*)value];
            [array addObject:item];
            [friMainDic setValue:array forKey:key];
        } else {
            NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)value;
            NSArray *array = @[dict,item];
            [friMainDic setValue:array forKey:key];
        }
    } else {
        [friMainDic setValue:item forKey:key];
    }
}
```

Comment: your explanation makes sense, and thanks, it's exactly what I need done to do what I need to do next...thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Well I guess I would approach it like this. Find out if there is an array already there. Make a mutable version and add to it. Set it back into the dictionary. If there isn't create an array and add to it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [friMainDicArray count]; i++)
{
    if (firMainDic[[friMainDicArray[i] valueForKey:@"start_time" ])
    {
        //pull out the array and add to it
        NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray: firMainDic[[friMainDicArray[i] valueForKey:@"start_time" ]]];
        [mutableArray addObject:friMainDicArray[i]];
        [friMainDic setValue:mutableArray forKey:[friMainDicArray[i] valueForKey:@"start_time" ] ];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *array = @[friMainDicArray[i]];
        [friMainDic setValue:array forKey:[friMainDicArray[i] valueForKey:@"start_time" ] ]
    }
}
```

Not 100% sure but I believe when you put a mutable array into a dictionary it comes out as a non mutable array. Either way this should at least get you started in the right direction.

Comment: I tried your solution, and it works, and exactly what I needed, unfortunately someone else answered first and it also worked, so I made that as the solution, but I gave you a vote up. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to store your `JSON` objects always in array regardless of whether `keys` are same or different. By this way, you would at least  avoid doing some sort of vague checks at every iteration like;

```
if ([dict[key] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
    NSMutableArray *values = (NSMutableArray *)dict[key];
    [values addObject:newObject];
}
else {
    NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:dict[key]];
    [values addObject:newObject];
}
```

Instead, I would populate the resulting dictionary by iterating over the array once using below approach: (*Assuming all JSON objects are NSDictionary instances now*)

```
NSArray *events = @[@{@"start_time": @"17:00", @"end_time": @"17:30", @"english_event": @"Lion Dance", @"english_performer": @"Legendary Group"},
                    @{@"start_time": @"17:30", @"end_time": @"18:00", @"english_event": @"Singing", @"english_performer": @"Ivan Cheong"},
                    @{@"start_time": @"20:00", @"end_time": @"21:00", @"english_event": @"Music", @"english_performer": @"Adam Cease"},
                    @{@"start_time": @"20:00", @"end_time": @"21:00", @"english_event": @"Music", @"english_performer": @"DJ Happee From Channel 93.3"},
                    @{@"start_time": @"21:00", @"end_time": @"22:00", @"english_event": @"Singing", @"english_performer": @"Between California and Summer"}];

NSMutableDictionary *resultDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[events enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *event, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    NSMutableArray *values = resultDict[event[@"start_time"]];

    if (values == nil) {
        values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        resultDict[event[@"start_time"]] = values;
    }
    [values addObject:event];
}];
```

**Note:** I couldn't find a shorter way including `collection operators`, `KVO accessors` etc, that actually will take `0(n)` for grouping dictionaries .